# Handling suggested edits adding new content to answers

Tags: discussion, review-queues, suggested-edits

I have stumbled upon some Suggested Edits on answers that attempt to add new content to the answer given by the poster.

Although some of these edits (like the [suggested edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/18501460) on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/662030/3908170)... or well [this edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/18501184)) *do* add valuable content to the answer (basically they expand or enhance the answer considerably), I am not sure that they *reflect the original intentions of the answerer*.

**What could be an appropriate way of handling such Suggested Edits?**

If this were the case for Community Wiki posts I think there would be no problem, as the post is owned by Community and everyone can/should contribute to it's enhancement. However, seeing this on answers owned by users makes me wonder if those edits should be approved or not.

Comment: Why not to reject them? An edit like that merits its own answer.

Comment: @yivi surely one can do that, but that valuable content that could merit its own answer would be lost in a way if rejected... plus, how can you encourage the one suggesting to write it's own answer?

Comment: You can reject with custom reason if you want to...

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov and can the one suggesting the edit see that reason? I guess they can if they access the suggestions they have done

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Reject.**

I asked [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/305096/350567) on MSE and a special part of the answer reads:

> Also note that you shouldn't be editing significant original works into another person's (non-Community Wiki) answer to begin with.

In practice, I would reject for **clearly conflicts with author's intent** or **attempt to reply** depending on content. In case someone has a lot of stuff to add, it's totally fine to post another answer starting with

> In addition to `$someone`'s answer, I would like to add that ...